# Robocopy Script with exceptions not working

Tags: batch-file, move, robocopy

I'm trying to move a bunch of folders from directory A to directory B. 
The folders I would like to move have .csvs and .jps inside.

Directory A contains the following files that must remain in directory A (bat, cmd, py, csv, txt). Basically, all subdirectories of Source directory go, while all files stay. Not sure how everyone else would do this?

Visually it looks like this

```
Directory A 
-Folder 1 (to be moved)

-Folder 2 (to be moved)

-Folder 3 (to be moved)

-Folder 4 (to be moved)

-cmd files

-python scripts

-csv files

-bat scripts
```

My code is below. It fails to move anything returns the following error:
Error 32 - 'Deleting Source Directory' is being used by another process (must be the batch script doing the command below). I'm glad it fails because I don't want to delete the source directory, I want to delete the subdirectories within the source directory. Any ideas?

```
robocopy /move SOURCE_DIR DESTINATION_DIR /XF *.cmd* *.log* *.py* *.csv* *.bat*
```

Should I make this a two command script instead? First one copies the subdirectories, and the second deletes them?

Comment: First thing I'd advise is to remove the unnecessary asterisks, e.g. `*.cmd *.log *.py *.csv *.bat`. I'd also suggest that you use the source then the destination before any of the options. I think you may need to use additional options, such as `/E` or `/S`, open a Command Prompt window, enter `robocopy /?` and read its usage information.

Comment: The `/MOVE` option moves (hence copies and deletes) both files and directories, so do you want to try `MOV` instead? The source cannot be deleted since it is most likely not empty due to the exclusions...

Comment: What about `for /D %%I in ("Directory A\*") do move "%%I" "Directory B\"`? If `Directory A` and `Directory B` are on same partition/drive as expected by this command line, just the file allocation table is updated, no data are really copied respectively moved.